# Efficient Java FIFO byte buffer for intense IO

Tags: java, data-structures

I need a FIFO ring buffer to temporarily store byte stream data, the buffer should has two internal position pointers, denoting the last read/write positions, respectively. Such that the read/write operations on the buffer maybe interleaved.
Is there any existing libraries for this that are efficiently implemented?

Comment: Your requirement implies the buffer should be thread safe as your reading and writing thread are most likely different. A general data structure for this is LMAX Disruptor as you could search for; it's highly efficient though a bit rigid in the way it affects the design pattern at module level. Your problem can potentially be done by Disruptor with buffer blocks in side. Otherwise, if you are after a single thread one, It's pretty easy to write up your own.

Comment: I posted a lock-free one [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12691/o1-lock-free-container) - it is fixed-size so may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: If you are doing IO, which is slow, do you really need a highly CPU efficient buffer?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, thanks, but it seems that your implementation doesn't guarantee that the consumers get the bytes in the exact same order that they were written into the buffer.

Comment: @Raedwald, you are quite right, I'll settle for not-so-efficient buffer if there is any.